# display values except those that are empty or zero

Tags: php

So I have a form with about 60 choices for colors where the customer enters the quantity of each color desired.
The following page is a "review" of the order. So I have defined all the variables so that I can display the quantities. What I would like to do is not display the colors that have a value of "" or "0".
Is this something that can be done?

Here is the head code...

```
<?PHP
$packSize = $_POST["packSize"];
$cost = $_POST[""];
//COLORS
$c000 = $_POST["c000"];
$c010 = $_POST["c010"];
$c020 = $_POST["c020"];
$c019 = $_POST["c019"];
$c021 = $_POST["c021"];
$c022 = $_POST["c022"];
$c025 = $_POST["c025"];
$c026 = $_POST["c026"];
// ect...
?>
```

In the body...

```
  <p>Color choices:<br>
<?php
echo "000 = ".$c000."<br/>".
"010 = ".$c010 ."<br/>".
"020 = ".$c020 ."<br/>".
"019 = ".$c019 ."<br/>".
"021 = ".$c021 ."<br/>".
"022 = ".$c022 ."<br/>".
"025 = ".$c025 ."<br/>".
"026 = ".$c026 ."<br/>".
// etc...
?>
```

Comment: You should really use array here, declaring 60 variables is way too much, and then just loop through results/values, and remove undesired values, with simple condition...

Comment: try [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring 60 variable, declare an array. Suppose you have color range from `c0` to  `c100` then declare an array `color = array();`. Also use `empty($var)` function to check empty value.

A short form of your code:

```
<?PHP
$packSize = $_POST["packSize"];
$cost = $_POST[""];
//COLORS 
$color = array();
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
   if($i<10 && !empty($_POST["c00".$i]))
          $color['c00'.$i] = $_POST["c00".$i];
   else if($i<100 && !empty($_POST["c0".$i]))
          $color['c0'.$i] = $_POST["c0".$i];
}

?>
```

// print

```
<p>Color choices:<br>
<?php
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
   if($i <10 && !empty($color['c00'.$i]){
       echo 'c00'.$i.'='$color['c00'.$i]."<br>";
   }
   else if($i <100 && !empty($color['c0'.$i]){
       echo 'c0'.$i.'='$color['c0'.$i]."<br>";
   }
}

// etc...
?>
```

Comment: I see how this might work but the numbering is not consecutive.

Comment: >numbering is not consecutive.
suppose missing numbers are all empty values. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have limited variables, otherwise you can define an array.
for this you can check post value like not empty of not blank before you print value like following way:

```
 <?php
$packSize = $_POST["packSize"];
$cost = $_POST[""];
//COLORS
if(!empty($_POST['c000']) && $_POST["c000"]!=0)
  $c000 = $_POST["c000"];
if(!empty($_POST['c010']) && $_POST["c010"]!=0)
  $c010 = $_POST["c010"];
if(!empty($_POST['c020']) && $_POST["c020"]!=0)
  $c020 = $_POST["c020"];
if(!empty($_POST['c019']) && $_POST["c019"]!=0)
  $c019 = $_POST["c019"];
if(!empty($_POST['c021']) && $_POST["c021"]!=0)
  $c021 = $_POST["c021"];
if(!empty($_POST['c022']) && $_POST["c022"]!=0)
  $c022 = $_POST["c022"];
if(!empty($_POST['c025']) && $_POST["c025"]!=0)
  $c025 = $_POST["c025"];
if(!empty($_POST['c026']) && $_POST["c026"]!=0)
  $c026 = $_POST["c026"];

?>
```

Comment: `isset` won't work it will return true even if the values empty. it just requires the variable to be defined to return true. and what if the value is blank instead of `0`

Comment: no need for ` && $_POST["c025"]!=0` that is already handled by empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be better way just add array on inputs in front end like

```
<input type="text" name="color['c000']" value="green">
<input type="text" name="color['c001']" value="blue">
```

From backend it easy to get all the colors

```
$color = $_POST['color']; // will give all the values
```

Edit: Here the **$_POST['color']**  will have array with corresponding key what we gave in input like in this case `['c000' => 'green', 'c001' => blue]`

In body

```
<p>Color choices:<br>    
    foreach($color as $key => $value ) {
        if (!empty($value)) {//it will check the '' and 0 values
            echo ltrim($key, 'c') " = ".$value."<br/>".
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't know why use duplicate check. what is the meaning of `|| $value != 0` in `if (!empty($value) || $value != 0)`?

Comment: `colour['c000']` ==> `$_POST['color']` how you will get `color` in post array?

Comment: no need sorry i total missed empty will consider o also right @bansi

Comment: @ruhul when we submit form with array inputs we will get all corresponding keys also

Comment: Typo `colour['c000']` & `$_POST['color'];`. May be your compiler know both American and British english. ;) :P